# systemd service inside kubernetes is unable to get the env

Tags: kubernetes, centos, systemd

I setup a Centos systemd service but I'm not able to read the kubernetes env variables. If I run the bash inside the pod I'm able to see env (such as _UI_SERVICE_PORT_TCP_443=443, KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_ADDR=10.202.0.1  or container=docker) but not when I execute a bash script as a service inside the container.

I also tried Type=forking and ExecStart=/bin/bash believing the executed bash will inherit the kubernetes env but it's clean.

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
PWD=/ LANG=en_US.UTF-8 SHLVL=1
_=/bin/printenv

[Unit] Description= script after boot on k8s After=e.service

[Service] Type=forking ExecStart=@BINDIR@/virtual_service.py
```

Comment: Are you running the systemd inside a docker container that is part of a pod?

Comment: yes. it's the official centos systemd container. systemd seems ok as i have no issues with running other services inside this container.

Comment: i used this image: https://hub.docker.com/r/centos/systemd/ with this change in the dockerfile: ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/sbin/init"]
CMD ["/usr/sbin/init"]

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be related to the handling of environment variables in `services`. From my understanding, the env vars are stripped when running as a service, so you won't have access to what bash sees when your process runs as a service..

[This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/44378) provides a good description and some workarounds.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for this.
/proc/1/environ contains the environment and i managed to read the env while i'm running as a service.
hope this will help someone in the future.